# php mysql limit doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am telling my sql script to generate this:

```
       $result=mysql_query("SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE thread_id=38 LIMIT 2,7");
```

I dont know why it happens, but it returns to me 7 comments (posts/results) rather than 5.

is my statment is wrong? or is it because when I refresh the page more html is added in addition to the previous html ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE thread_id=38 LIMIT 2,5");
// Maybe you want to use (0,5) instead!?
```

#### Examples

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 0, 10 
// This will display the first 10 results from the database.

SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 5, 5
// This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10
```

Comment: it selects 5 rows and presents them

Comment: (x,5) will skip the first x row(s). Use (0,5) to get the first 5 rows.

Answer (score 4):

The clause `Limit X, Y` included at the end of the select query means `X` is the starting point (remember the first record is `0`) and `Y` is the number records to display.

To get 5 records starting from 2nd record you have to specify: `limit 2,5`.

Answer (score 1):

Second argument should be count, not last element. (2,5) in your case

Comment: hmmm. so how do I get one number from another number :(

Comment: You may subtract second from first in your example

Answer (score 1):

By your example everything correct.

MySQL Limit first value telling from what row need to start, and the second value how much result need to return.

```
SELECT comment_id FROM comments WHERE thread_id=38 LIMIT 5
```

Will return first 5 rows